# Django add reply messages

Tags: django

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <form class="reply-form" method="post" action="reply/{{message.id}}/">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="{{ message.id }}" value="{{ message.id }}">
      <div class="form-group">
         <textarea name="text" cols="60" rows="2" maxlength="4096" required="" id="id_text"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
   </form>
</div>
```

I am trying to use the above to reply to a message. How would I use the message id to add a reply to that message from the action using views?

**post only view That should just save it to the Messages.**

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def reply(request,messageID):
    print(messageID)
    return redirect('home')
```

urls.py

```
path('reply/<int:messageID>/', reply, name='reply')
```

models.py

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name='sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name='receiver',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(default='',max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(default='',max_length=4096)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            null=True, blank=True, related_name='contact_parent')

    def get_children(self):
        return Messages.objects.filter(parent=self)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} to {} :{}'.format(self.sender,self.receiver,self.text)
```

I created a message like so

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=4096, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = ('receiver','subject','text',)
```

views.py

```
elif 'sendMessage' in request.POST:
    sendMessageForm = MessageForm(request.POST or None,)
    if sendMessageForm.is_valid(): 
        sendMessageFormUser =  sendMessageForm.save(commit=False)
        sendMessageFormUser.sender = request.user
        sendMessageFormUser.save()
        unreadMessagesCount = Messages.objects.filter(Q(receiver=request.user) & Q(read=False)).count()
        context['unreadMessagesCount'] = unreadMessagesCount
        return redirect('home')
```

Comment: You could make a POST only view whit a unique url where the id of the message is stored, then add that to the `action="/messages/<pk>/reply"`. You will need to perform the necessary checks to make sure the POST is legit in that view, and then possibly redirect.

Comment: I ran it like this                         <form class="reply-form" method="POST" action="reply/{{message.id}}/">

Comment: This currently display the messageID but currently no clue how to put replies to it.

Comment: I struggled with this as well, This guy has a good video on it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcAp-O4q_Vk

Comment: I got it working I think not too sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def reply(request,messageID):
    print(messageID)
    parent = Messages.objects.get(id=messageID)
    #Not sure how the receiver is found
    reply = Messages.objects.create(text=request.POST['text'], receiver=parent.sender, sender=request.user, parent=parent)
    print(parent)
    print(reply)
    print(request.POST)
    return redirect('home')
```

I just needed a post only view and then grab the message which belongs to that id and from there create a new message that points the parent to itself. Obviously right now it's all pointing to the top message instead of the replies I think I'm not really sure.

Comment: This is the solution, no? You created a new message and set the parent to the right message? I would maybe check some things like ´parent.sender = request.user´ for safety. What is not yet working as you want?

Comment: It all points to the messageid i think which I'd probably want them to reference to the previous reply. So it's like a list for 1 message instead of each referencing each other. So the parent needs to somehow get the last reply.

Comment: `I'd probably want them to reference to the previous reply` => that's what you just did, by setting the message it answers to as parent and the sender of the message to answer as receiver. That way it is possible that 1 message has more answers (=list). Or do I misunderstand you?